# Image sliding from left to right infinitely

Tags: android, android-animation

I wish to have an animated background like this gif:
[image] .
I don't have a mac or adobe after effects software to create a `lottie json` for such animation, and i want a more command over animation than simply using a gif. From what i have read over the internet, I have to use either `TransitionManager` or `TranslationAnimation` , but i am unable to figure out the correct code for it.

I am also interested in knowing if there is a plugin, or some way to make minor edits to already available lottie files like background color change , items color change, items removal, etc just like the way we could do for simple vector images(**Using Android Studio**, or at the very least, some free software). I found [this](https://lottiefiles.com/1800-sky) lottie file which was doing a very great job for me, but i couldn't modify its colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it! When i logged the values of some variables like `view.getX()` or `view.getRootView().getX()`, i was able to figure out, that my view will have its location as 0,0 . so After that it was all a need for finding the screen size to finally  make this infinite cloud moving animation. I am not sure if this function is good in terms of memory or performance , but on my device, its running smoothly.

```java
 private void showCloudMovingContinuouslyAnimation(View v) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int runtimeScreenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int totalDuration = runtimeScreenWidth*5;

        int viewPositionX = 0, viewPositionY = 0;
        TranslateAnimation outToRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                viewPositionX, (runtimeScreenWidth / 2f) + 50,
                viewPositionY, viewPositionY);
        outToRight.setDuration(totalDuration / 2);
        outToRight.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        TranslateAnimation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                -((runtimeScreenWidth / 2f) + 50), viewPositionX,
                viewPositionY, viewPositionY
        );
        inFromLeft.setDuration(totalDuration / 2);
        inFromLeft.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);


        boolean shouldRemainThereAfterAnimationFinishes = true;// useful when animating for single time


        AnimationSet animationSet=new AnimationSet(true);
        animationSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animationSet.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animationSet.addAnimation(inFromLeft);
        animationSet.addAnimation(outToRight);

        v.startAnimation(animationSet); // start animation


    }
```